# What effect does transposing the matrix of a linear transformation have on the transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I came across the following result in a book on Mathematical Physics, where it's given without proof. This is related to: [How to prove that a homogeneous system of equations along with its "transposed" system contain the same number of linearly independent solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898770/how-to-prove-that-a-homogeneous-system-of-equations-along-with-its-transposed).

But I'm trying to prove it **using minimal concepts related to matrices (i.e. no row echelon, etc.)**, so I'm not interested in the answer to the linked question.

> For the system of equations:
> $$\tag1 \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}x_k = y_i, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (i=1,2,\ldots, n)$$
>
> the following alternative holds: Either it has one and only one solution $\bf{x}$ for each arbitrarily given vector $\bf{y}$, in particular the solution $\bf{x}=0$ for $\bf{y}=0$; or, alternatively, the homogeneous equations arising from $(1)$ (when $\bf{y}=0$) have a positive number $m$ of nontrivial  linearly independent solutions $\bf x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$, which may be assumed to be normalized. In the latter case, the "transposed" homogeneous system of equations
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n a'_{ik}x_k = 0, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (i=1,2,\ldots, n)$$
>
> where $a'_{ik} = a_{ki}$, also has exactly $m$ linearly independent nontrivial solutions $\bf x'_1, x'_2, \ldots x'_m$. The inhomogeneous system $(1)$ then possesses solutions for just those vectors $\bf y$ which are orthogonal to $\bf x'_1, x'_2, \ldots x'_m$. These solutions are determined only to within an additive term which is an arbitrary solution of the homogeneous system of equations, i.e. if $\bf x$ is a solution of the inhomogeneous system and $\bf x_j$ is any solution of the homogeneous system, then $\bf x+x_j$ is also a solution of the inhomogeneous system.

The system can be viewed as a linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Either $\dim(\ker(T)) = m > 0$ (i.e. the homogeneous equations arising from $(1)$ (when $\bf{y}=0$) have a positive number $m$ of nontrivial  linearly independent solutions), or it is a singleton. In the latter case the linear map is injective, hence bijective (since source and target dimensions are the same). If it's bijective, obviously for any vector $\bf y$ there's a unique preimage (or solution) $\bf x$. This takes care of the first part.

The last part is also clear: if $\bf x_j$$~= (x_{j1}, x_{j2}, \ldots, x_{jn})$ and $\bf x$$~=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, then

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}(x_k+x_{jk}) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}x_k+\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}x_{jk} = y_i+0 = y_i$$

Assuming that $T'$ is the linear transformation corresponding to the "transposed" system of equations, the middle part essentially states that $\dim(\ker(T)) = \dim(\ker(T')) = m$, and that $\ker(T')$ and $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ are orthogonal subspaces. How do these 2 facts follow? What effect does transposing the matrix of $T$ have on the resultant transformation $T'$?

Obviously matrices are involved, but I'd still appreciate an answer that relies more on basic principles rather than too many matrix results.

Comment: I take it from the second half of your question that your whish to use "minimal concepts related to matrices" does not exclude any "more advanced" concepts?

Comment: @mol3574710n0fN074710n : I confess I don't know the advanced concepts for matrices. So far I've read the first half of Lang's linear algebra book and it doesn't cover much of matrices/determinants, etc. (unlike Hoffman, Kunze). i.e. more abstract than computational, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hm. Ok, so an appropriate answer for you would better not contain any functional-analytic stuff, I guess... Pondering about something elementary that does not rely on too much technical stuff. (I assume the struggle with indices is what you want to avoid the most...)

Comment: @mol3574710n0fN074710n: Nah I don't have a problem with indices. Functional analysis would be overkill for finite dimensional linear algebra though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:
If $v\in\ker A$
  then $v\perp a^{i}$
  for $i=1,\dots,n$
  where $a^{i}$
  denote the rows of $A$. Thus $v\perp\overline{\mathtt{span}}\left\{ a^{i}\;\vert\; i=1,\dots,n\right\}$. The $a^{i}$ are also the columns of $A^{T}$. And $\overline{\mathtt{span}}\left\{ a^{i}\;\vert\; i=1,\dots,n\right\} =\mathtt{im}\, A^{T}$ (with appropriate transpose of the vectors).

Comment: Okay, so the main point is that the columns of a matrix span the image of the corresponding linear transformation. I guess that explains the first part too, since images of both transformations have the same dimension, by rank-nullity theorem, so should their kernels.

Comment: Exactly, I think you got the idea!